# Could I know why my comment was deleted?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

Yesterday, I commented on 2 similar answers provided by the same user, one of them was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62381027/1238965).

The solution is really wrong and to be avoided so I placed a comment saying something along those lines: *"This is wrong. These class names are undocumented and shouldn't be used ..."* and also maybe suggested the user to remove the answer (can't remember exactly since we can't find deleted comments anywhere).

Today, I can see that both comments were deleted.

Could I know why it was deleted? (I have added again a similar comment that is still visible for now).

If my comment was deleted, I believe it's because I made a *mistake* somewhere. But how can we learn from our *mistakes* if we don't know what we did wrong?

Comment: Because someone flagged it as (probably as "no longer needed") and a mod obliged. It's better not to get overly attached to comments. They can be deleted at any moment. Things that need to last are better posted as questions or answers.

Comment: I do understand that someone has flagged it. But I'd be interested to know *what flag* was used, and *why* a moderator considered it inappropriate. Is there anything wrong with commenting on an answer and saying the solution is wrong and should be avoided (with reasons)? Especially when it was accepted as the answer **and** it is wrong?

Comment: @MrUpsidown *"Is there anything wrong with commenting on an answer and saying the solution is wrong and should be avoided (with reasons)?"* - No

Comment: Right, then I'd like to know why it was deleted. I don't think it was rude or condescending in any way so I simply don't understand why it was removed. To me, that comment was much more useful to the community than an accepted answer providing wrong information.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It was deleted because three different users flagged it as "harassment, bigotry, or abuse". Three flags on a comment will cause it to be automatically deleted.

For transparency, the full text of your comment was:

> **Warning**: `.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c` or any other class name within the output HTML of a Google Maps map are **undocumented** and therefore should **not be used**. You do know that apparently. So why do you provide this as an answer?

I confess I have no idea how anyone could consider that to be "harassment, bigotry, or abuse". I am looking into this further to see if the flags cast on that comment might have been the result of some sort of funny business.

I would reinstate your comment, but you've already posted a modified version of it, which I think is preferable because it avoids the potentially unfriendly accusation of malice found in your original comment.

Comment: I would guess: *"You do know that apparently. So why do you provide this as an answer?"* was the trigger for people /shrug, how ***3*** people came to that conclusion though is beyond me.

Comment: I could maybe follow an "unfriendly" flag. But "harassment, bigotry, or abuse"? No.

Comment: Yeah well, IIRC there has still always been some confusion for which is which... I tend to only ever use the U/U flag. I certainly don't disagree with you

Comment: Found some funny business, BTW. Not as funny as advertised.

Comment: *"You do know that apparently"* was a reference to a sentence in the answer itself mentioning the class names are subject to change (undocumented) and that the user who answered apparently is a *Google Maps Technical Support Ninja* as I can see on the profile (I don't know if this is official or not btw...). So I think it's quite inappropriate to file an answer when you do know it's a bad one.

Comment: Understood, @MrUpsidown, but in the future please try to focus strictly on the content itself, rather than making any judgments about the user who happens to post it.

Comment: OK, I must admit I could have avoided the last part of my comment. But I am a bit disappointed by this user's answers in general as she/he/they provided already many *1st level support* answers on questions that should be closed (duplicates, or off-topic questions most of the time, asking about billing or other basic questions that can be easily answered be reading the documentation and that do not involve programming). I believe SO is not the place for such basic *product support* and got a bit irritated by this low quality answer. Thanks anyway for looking into it!

Comment: Did this really answer the question? I am in similar (less severe and maybe less justified) situation and would like to know what the correct course of action is. Should I also ask new question on meta? Or is there some other way or plan to streamline this process? Is there a way to know which of my comments were deleted and what flags were used? Is it abuse to tell other users they behave unapproprietly but it's not abuse to falsely flag them?